# how to append array in formData ,array in which includes 2 values with keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipartform-data

**Code :**

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let array1;

array1 = [{ "subfolder_name": subfolder, "file_upload": file }];
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append("folder_name",folder );
formData.append("counselor",array1 );
```

> it return counselor:[Object Object]

Comment: File which is an image ,Am trying to append array1 into counselor,but in return am getting [Object Object]

Comment: Could you provide some more context? It would be useful to see the code that is returning the unwanted counselor:[Object Object] and also it would be useful to see the bigger picture. What are you trying to do in general?

Comment: Am trying to post a parameter 'folder_name' and 'counselor folder',In counselor value am adding an array ,in that array which includes sub_folder as a text value and file_upload as  one iimage upload ,these all am trying in angular 4

Comment: The only valid types for FormData's field-value are USVString and Blob/File. To send an object structure, you will have to stringify it (generally with `JSON.stringify`). File objects can't be stringified, you will have to give them their own field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FormData` is an interface to construct set of key-value pairs, therefore, it does not support any kind of nested structure, but you could, however, denote nesting in the key like so:

```js
let array1 = [{ "subfolder_name": "foo", "file_upload": "bar" }];
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('counselor[0].subfolder_name', array1[0].subfolder_name );
formData.append('counselor[0].file_upload', array1[0].file_upload );

for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: "file_upload" key value which is a file(image) and am getting [Obejtc Object]

Comment: @sam_programmer you clearly stated that `counselor` returns `[Object Object]` which is, in fact, an Array. You can find possible ways to append a file in [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload).

Comment: Only issue is name="counselor_folder[]" ,this counselor_folder is showing empty on second value

Comment: Could you please provide more details? It's unclear what leads to this problem.

Comment: The subfolder_name and file_upload key is missing in output,only am getting its value inside counselor

Comment: You can specify property names in key as well, I've updated my answer to match structure of `array1` variable

Comment: In this format: counselor{ subfolder_name:value, file_upload:value }

Comment: In this case, you just need to remove an index(`[0]`) from the key.